# How to show a text editor in a div and show the added content after a button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a box like `div` and an `ADD` button. So when I click on `add` button, a `text editor` should appear and I should be able to add my text and contents and finally when I click `ok` it should show the added content in the `div`. If I click `cancel`,it should show old div with `ADD` button.

What has to be the logic for this? I will try to code it myself.

Comment: you can make a popup in which a div will open and make that div editable

Comment: share your code

Comment: something like a modal? Modal is not my requirement. I need to show a text editor in that box like div..add content click save.....it will be shown in the div

Comment: If i understand correctly, wouldn't you want to use <textarea>. Also, please at least attempt before posting a question: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: @SanjayKumar stuck with logic..once I get the logic I will start coding..I am trying to code myself

Comment: @RyanB no its not a textarea,, its quill text editor... Yea once the logic is clear I will code,,sorry

Comment: Please refresh yourself with  what types of question are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site

Comment: Logic is already in the question. You should write your code now.

Comment: I have given some idea you can design it as your need and also the logic should be clear to you now

Comment: Add controls of  `textarea`,`ok` button, and `cancel` button inside the div and hide it on load. once you click `add` make the controls visible and hide `add` button. on click `ok` update text inside div and make `add` visible and hide controls. If you click cancel simply make `add` visible and hide controls.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that, by text-editor, you are referring to an element with prepopulated text that can be edited, you could use contenteditable attribute on a div. With this you could preserve some of the formatting.

As you mentioned, I'm going to refrain from posting the exact code. You could take hints from the following:

Attach an event listener on the ADD button that can add contenteditable attribute to the text-editor element in the markup

If there was a `<div id="text-editor">Some text here</div>`

```
addButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('text-editor').setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');
})
```

On clicking the element with the text "Some text here" can be edited as you like. Clicking on OK, you could simply remove the contenteditable attribute

```
okButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('text-editor').removeAttribute('contenteditable');
})
```

Clicking cancel, and reverting would mean, you should have cached the earlier state of the text editor prior to editing. So, modify the add button listener

```
let oldState = '';
let textEditorElement = document.getElementById('text-editor');
addButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  oldState = textEditorElement.innerHTML;
  textEditor.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');
})
```

And on cancel, you can simple revert to `oldState`,

```
cancelButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  textEditor.innerHTML = oldState;
  textEditor.removeAttribute('contenteditable');
})
```

For a full fledged text editor, check out [DraftJS](https://draftjs.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Following is my logic :

1, You need a css property `display` to hide your `text editor`, and then you can use Javascript to control your `text editor` hiding/showing by `display`. Also you can use `display` to hide/show every element you want.

2, Other thing is how to get and set value to your `text editor`, Once you get that you can add/edit/delete the value of `text editor`.

If you have any questions, please give me a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Check this whether it fulfills your need or not

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
#myP{
height:200px;
width:200px;
border:1px dashed black;
}
</style>
<div id="myP" contenteditable="false">Click the try button to make me editable</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<button onclick="myFunction1()">Add</button>

<div id="demo"></div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myP").contentEditable="true";

}
function myFunction1() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myP").contentEditable;
    var y = document.getElementById("myP").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="hello";
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can make any element editable using contenteditable attribute

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#add').on('click',function(){
  $('textarea').show();
  var text = $('textarea').val();  
  $('#content').text(text);
});

$('#cancel').on('click',function(){
  $('textarea').val("").hide();
  $('#content').text("Your div content here");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
 Your div content here
</div>
<textarea style="display:none"></textarea>
<button id="add">ADD</button> <button id="cancel">CANCEL</button>
```